# Why is it necessary to remove skins from soybeans before making soymilk?

Tags: soy, tofu, soymilk

I have made soymilk and tofu a few times. All the recipes I have looked at say that you must remove the skins from soybeans before making soymilk, but none of the recipes explain why you must do this. It's kind of a pain and I'd like to skip that step if I could do so without ruining the end product. Do you know why it is suggested that we remove the skins from soybeans before making soymilk and if it is worth the time and effort?
Thank you very much for your advice!

Comment: Are you starting with dried beans?

Comment: I am starting with dried beans. I soak them for 8-12 hours typically.

Comment: I personally leave the skins, and even put in the ones that come off when rinsing. I like the texture and fibre never hurt anyone.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of the advice to remove skins from re-hydrated soybeans before processing into soy milk. It does sound like a hassle (is it even possible?). I just grind them in a quality blender before heating.  I've never noticed any problem.

Comment: Hi Moscafj, thanks for your response. It is possible to remove a number of skins by rubbing the soaked soybeans between your hands in a bowl of water and then skimming the skins off the top (because the skins float and the beans sink) but it is a pain in the butt. I think I will try not doing it the next time I make soymilk and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Some people believe it causes a beany flavor. To me it adds to the fragrance.  I even use the soak water when grinding.  While it is unnecessary for soymilk and tofu, it is necessary for tempeh as the intact skins are a barrier to fermentation.  Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had once made it without the skin. It was still beany. Then after that I never deskin them. They do say deskinning 'removes' the beany flavour but for me it doesn't work.